# Core Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Does the Core Reporting API show exactly what analytics data is stored on Google's servers?

I have some Events and Page Views filtered out on various Analytics Profiles and was under the impression that even though they were filtered out and do not appear in the GA UI itself, they were still sent to Google's servers.

Therefore, I would have expected to see the filtered out data in the API. However, I can't see anything at all when I run a query for the filtered out Events.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The data is sent to the property so it collects everything you send to it, but you can see/query only the data of a view so if you apply a filter you can only query the filtered data.

Comment: Hi - so do Google retain the unfiltered data, or is it purged after it is processed and surfaced in the the reporting API? I'm guessing this is a question only Google themselves would be able to answer!

Comment: The question is that data are available in the views, so it is best practice to always have an unfiltered view.